# deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange equivalent in swift 3 to delete characters one by one from last index of string

Tags: swift, string, character

I have user input string which contains characters. I want to delete those characters one by one from its last index when I tap button until the string is empty
Here is my string variable

```
@IBAction func btnBackSpaceAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.userInput.characters.count >= 1{
        let string = String(self.userInput.characters.dropLast())
        print(string)
    }
}
```

How to delete characters from last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
var string = "Good Morning" // Your string

@IBAction func bnuttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) { //Your button action
    string = String(string.characters.dropLast())
    if !string.isEmpty {            
        print(string)
    }
    else {
        print("String is Empty")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Good Mornin
Good Morni
Good Morn
Good Mor
Good Mo
Good M
...
```

Comment: Have you replace the result with your original string, edit your question with your current code

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.

Comment: don't use count to check if the collection is empty string has isEmpty property exactly for that `if !string.isEmpty` BTW which is totally unecessary `string = String(string.characters.dropLast())` would never return nil

Comment: from the docs **To check whether a collection is empty, use its isEmpty property instead of comparing count to zero. Unless the collection guarantees random-access performance, calculating count can be an O(n) operation.
Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection.**

Comment: @LeoDabus You are right thanks for the suggestion, Edited answer with it, but still use `isEmpty` to specify the string is empty now